# KeyStore and TrustStore mismatch

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

I have a customer who replaced the keystore and truststore of our product components. After replacement the components can't communicate with each other (2 way SSL).

On SSL logs I see:
`http-nio-8100-exec-2, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
%% Invalidated:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
http-nio-8100-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-nio-8100-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8100-exec-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain`

They have configured the same keystore and truststore files on both sides.
I've opened their keystore and truststore and this is how they are built:
**keystore**
entry1 - server
cert[1] MD5:  X
cert[2] MD5:  Y
cert[3] MD5:  Z

**truststore**
entry1 - root
cert[1] MD5:  Z
entry2 - intermediate
cert[1] MD5:  Y

It seems to me that the fact that cert[1] in the keystore (with MD5 X) is missing from the truststore is problematic.

Am I right?

Can you see any other problem with the way their keystore and truststore was built?

Comment: Do you components communicate both ways or is or is it a client-server architecture? Is it 1-way or 2-way SSL?

Comment: 2 way. I will update the question as well.

Comment: If it's 2-way SSL, you should have a keystore and truststore on either side of the fence, which you haven't specified in your question. Your also aren't clear which way it fails. You need to be more specific in your post.

Comment: Thanks. I've added to the question: They have configured the same keystore and truststore files on both sides.
Does it still matter which way it fails?

Comment: The direction shouldn't matter in that case. Is cert[1] in the keystore a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Actually I don't know. Is there way to check using keytool or any other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108509/discussion-between-rzet-and-danieln).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is related to some missing certificates either in your ***keystore*** and/or ***truststore***.

Generally speaking, when the client sends a request to the server, the server presents its certificate chain which must include the server's certificate as the first entry followed by its issuer and other issuers. Each following certificate must directly certify the one preceding it unless it is present in the ***truststore*** on the client-side.

You need to check whether your ***cert[1]*** in ***keystore*** is a self-signed certificate. You can achieve this in the following way:

For .jks Java keystore type:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore [keystore-file-name].jks
```

-For #PKCS12 keystore type:

```
keytool -list -keystore [keystore-file-name].p12 -storetype PKCS12 -v
```

When the certificate is printed, check the **'*Issuer*'** attribute.

**If it matches the '*Owner*' attribute, it means it's a self-signed certificate and you need to add the '*cert[1]*' into the *truststore*.**

If they don't match, try one of the following alternatives:

- Generate a new ***'cert[1]'*** signed by either ***'Y'*** or
  ***'Z'*** and add it into the ***keystore*** or replace the existing one. The decision whether to replace it or add depends how your code reads the certificate. A replacement might be a better option.
- Add the current ***'Issuer'*** of ***'cert[1]'*** of the ***keystore*** into the
  ***truststore***.

If the certificate of the ***'Issuer'*** of ***'cert[1'*** in the ***keystore*** is already present in the ***truststore***, I would've expected the SSL handshake to be successful.

**Here is how you add an issuer to a truststore:**

1) Get hold of the Public Certificate of the ***issuer***, which is stored in ***.cer*** file. If the ***issuer*** is self-generated and you've got access to its ***keystore***, the certificate an be exported from there using the following command:

```
keytool -export -keystore [issuer-keystore].jks -alias [alias]-file [output-file-name].cer
```

2) Import the ***.cer*** file into the ***truststore***:

```
keytool -importcert -file [output-file-name].cer -keystore [truststore-file-name].jks -alias [alias]
```

Comment: Issuer and Owner for cert[1] doesn't match, does it mean it's self signed?
cert[2] owner and issuer doesn't match as well, cert[3] owner and issuer does match.

Comment: One more question - after I'll create a new cert[1] I need to replace it with the existing one, right? not just add it.

Comment: Can you also explain what is causing the problem?

Comment: Thank you. How can I add the issuer of cert[1] to the truststore?

Comment: I've updated my answer. However, the information you were looking for is also available on the internet. You really need to be specific in you post if you need an accurate and speedy answer. Otherwise voting will go against your post. Please specify as much information as possible to avoid lengthy conversations using comments. Always happy to help.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved by adding cert[1] to the truststore.
BTW, I was confused as I didn't understand what you mean by adding the Issuer, rather than adding the certificate.

Comment: I'm not sure what steps you followed to fix this problem but if cert[1] is the certificate presented by the server, you should not need to add it to the truststore unless it's self-signed certificate. Imagine your browser talking to many HTTPS services, it doesn't need to store their SSL certificates since the verification is based on the trusted issuers installed in the browser which are used to verify the cert send by the server in the SSL handshake. I'm puzzled. BTW. When I said 'Issuer' I meant its certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right?

No. As long as the truststore contains one of the certificates in the keystore's certificate chain, it should trust the certificate in the KeyStore.

Comment: See in my question, I've attached the error from Java's SSL Log

Comment: Moreover, what doesn't work: After replacement the components can't communicate with each other.